# Is it possible to reprocess existing table and how?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a few tables and would like to reprocess everything into one table. Is it possible?

I used "verbal" explanation of the situation, hope it is understandable.

i.e. I have table1 with column1 and column2.

```
Record1 contains column1_stringA and column2_stringB.
Record2 contains column1_stringC and column2_stringB.
```

I want to put that record into `table2 (column1, column2, column3) where column3 = if table1.column1.value = "column1_stringA" return column3_A, else return column3_C.`

P.S.: I can't export as csv as it has nested elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that a current limitation is that every resultset gets flattened, so for now it'd not be possible to keep the nested structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a select of your tables using JOIN and the [IF](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#otherfunctions) operator to get exactly the results you would want inserted.

Then you can run the select adding your table2 as a destination, as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622526/google-bigquery-create-a-table-from-a-query-result)

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write program using BigQuery.Table API - using get & insert functions (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables)
because: BigQuery tables are append-only (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#deletingrows)