# BigQuery randomnly fails with /bigquery/v2/projects/<project>/queries/>jobID-HEX 404 not found

Tags: perl, google-bigquery

I am getting random failures from the Big Query API when I send it some SQL to fetch data over the REST API.

the REST point I am using is

https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${project}/queries

Sometimes I get results and sometimes not.

I found a similar issue on the web where the error was caused by the location parameter being defaulted to 'US', so I tried 'EU' and a couple of my queries worked but some still failed.
The queries do take a while to run, (5 minutes) .

I am able to run it okay in the console.

Any help with where to look would be much appreciated

The error I get looks like this (PS: I did not create that job id returned in the error

```
Query failed: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/bigquery/v2/projects/$project/queries/job_F6t2Lvufj01Eo1PyuUZuyUiIUwZA</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I have tried with no location and also changing the location from US to EU with no luck. I'm based in the UK and the dataset I am querying has the location set to US

below is the perl code that runs the query.

sub query {

```
my ( $self, $sql, %params ) = @_;

my $url
    = "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/$self->{project}/queries";

my $res
    = %params
    ? $self->request( $url,
    { query => $sql, useLegacySql => \0, %params } )
    : $self->request( $url, { query => $sql, useLegacySql => \0 } );

croak "Query failed: $res->{content}" unless $res->{success};

my $job_id = $res->{content}{jobReference}{jobId};

my $attempts;

# If the result set takes longer to build than the default BigQuery
# timeout (10 seconds), we need to poll an endpoint to gather the results.
# We attempt this up to n times before giving up.
until ( $res->{content}{jobComplete} ) {
    $res
        = %params
        ? $self->request( "$url/$job_id", \%params )
        : $self->request("$url/$job_id");

    croak "Query failed: $res->{content}" unless $res->{success};

    croak 'Query failed: result set took too long to return'
        if ++$attempts > MAX_ATTEMPTS;
}

my @fields = map $_->{name}, @{ $res->{content}{schema}{fields} };

sub {
    my @rows;

    for ( @{ delete $res->{content}{rows} // [] } ) {
        push @rows, \my %row;

        @row{@fields} = map $_->{v}, @{ $_->{f} };
    }

    if ( $res->{content}{pageToken} ) {
        my $url = "$url/$job_id?";

        $url .= HTTP::Tiny->www_form_urlencode(
            { pageToken => $res->{content}{pageToken} } );

        $res
            = %params
            ? $self->request( $url, \%params )
            : $self->request($url);

        croak "Query failed: $res->{content}" unless $res->{success};
    }

    @rows;
};
```

}

I expect the rows that are pulled returned when I run the same SQL in the console to be returned over the API in a consistent way.

Actual result is, sometimes the REST point fails with 404 job id not found

Comment: It may be a DNS issues for the API endpoint Google uses.

Comment: It may be because of the timeout. Check the Stackdriver logging and the query history in the BQ UI for the complete error message. If it does not complete within the specified time then get the jobID then use https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults method to fetch the result once it completes.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, I have the timeout set at 2 hours. In general I would expect tBigQuery, as a data warehouse product, to handle long running queries

Comment: @EdmundAdjei  I am getting the same issue , is it solved ?

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout when calling the API endpoint is [10 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest.FIELDS.timeout_ms), this is for the request not for the query.

The query timeout for BigQuery itself is [six hours](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs)