# How to override default time out for BigQuery method calls

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I understand that default timeout of BigQuery is 1 Minute. I would like to know if there is any way to override default time out value either during invoking a Operation method or while initializing BigQuery client. I see a timeout option for job in BigQuery documentation but in my case I am doing integration to BigQuery without Job.

I tried passing 'timeoutMs:1' in options to method call but it has no effect Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the official [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/6438df629e9adb707338bd53959c7c10e0ae2936/src/bigquery.ts#1626), the `query` operation refers to `job.query` and its mentioned that we can see the complete options set at this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#request-body).

[image]

In the mentioned page we can find the following information about `timeoutMs`:

> Optional. How long to wait for the query to complete, in milliseconds,
> before the request times out and returns. Note that this is only a
> timeout for the request, not the query. If the query takes longer to
> run than the timeout value, the call returns without any results and
> with the 'jobComplete' flag set to false. You can call
> jobs.getQueryResults() to wait for the query to complete and read the
> results. The default value is 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds).

As this page is mentioned as the complete reference, I conclude that this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try to run it as a job, instead of a query:

```
const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
// Wait for the query to finish
const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
// Print the results
console.log(`Rows: ${rows}`);
```

Also, the timeoutMs is in milliseconds. Here's a full list of the options available in the options object:
[Method: jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks, butI have requirement where in I don't want to use Job.

Comment: Did you try adjusting timeoutMs to larger number in the options objects? What happens if you set it to larger than 1 minute? Or less?

Comment: There is no effect at all. I  executed a query which will take some time to get records, that is why i tried adding timeoutMs as 1 ms to check if i get timeout error but that is not the case

Comment: Maybe google have a value validation, because I guess no query will finish in 1ms. If you didn't try by now, try setting it to 10000 (10 seconds), and see what happens then.