# How to create a table from a view in BigQuery using the UI?

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-view

How do we create a table from a view in BigQuery using the UI?

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622526/google-bigquery-create-a-table-from-a-query-result) in SO but it appears to require a programmatic call to the API. Is there a method to do this using the UI?

Previously we read that BigQuery has a limit to the number of derived views from a table (the limit is 8) but that any view can be materialized into a table thus enabling further derived subviews. We are unable to find the mechanism to do that in the BigQuery documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Save As Table" option just above the results after running a query to create a view.

Comment: I don't see such option. Can you please point out where do you see it? Or is it removed? I can only create new view from it; not table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do this with the simple click of a button, but one way you can do this is by using the "Create Table" SQL statement on the UI:

```
CREATE TABLE `your_project_id.your_dataset_id.your_new_table_name`
AS
SELECT *
FROM `your_project_id.your_dataset_id.your_view_name`;
```

This will create a new table in the specified dataset of your project, assuming you have permissions to create new tables in that dataset. You can also edit the columns or match rows you need instead of using `SELECT *`