# Write from a query to table in BigQuery only if query is not empty

Tags: python, google-bigquery

In BigQuery it's possible to write to a new table the results of a query. I'd like the table to be created only whenever the query returns at least one row. Basically I don't want to end up creating empty table. I can't find an option to do that. (I am using the Python library, but I suppose the same applies to the raw API)

Comment: Can't you use some sort of defaults? If EMPTY then use default value?

Comment: @xCloudx8 not sure we are on the same page. I am talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634697/825190

Comment: I don't get it either, every query in bigquery creates already a table, even if it's anonymous. There must be a 2nd op that rewrites some table if it's not empty. You cannot avoid this as far I know.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to specify the destination on the query definition and you don't know what it will return when you run it can you tack a `LIMIT 1` to the end?

You can check the row number in the [job result object](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#query) and then re run the query without the limiter if there are results into your new table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this. Of course, one can do it in two steps, as you suggest. My question is about doing it within one call.

Comment: I have not been in BigQuery for that long but it does not seem like you can do what you're asking. The query runs and puts the results either into a table or into memory/application and that has to be defined before the query runs.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to do this in one step. I'd recommend running the query, inspecting the results, and then performing a table copy with WRITE_TRUNCATE to commit the results to the final location if the intermediate output contains at least one row.