# 'Create Table As' in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to create a table on the basis of result of `select` query in BigQuery?

For example:

```
create table abc as select x,y,z from mnp;
```

Is there any way or workaround to achieve the same in BigQuery?

Any leads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a table from query results in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622526/create-a-table-from-query-results-in-google-bigquery)

Comment: In addition to using the SDKs, you can also do it directly in the console (_Show Options_ > _Destination Table_)

Comment: There is an active effort to support DDL statements in BigQuery. You could consider submitting a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) for CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ... to get an update when it is available.

Comment: Bigquery now supports this. The query given in your example will work.

Answer (score 16):

Just try giving the GCP dataset name before table name in create table statement.

Example:

```
create table `GCP_Dataset.abc` as select x,y,z from mnp
```

Comment: At Feb 2021, I am getting **Cannot set write disposition in jobs with DDL statements**

Comment: @Nabin You may have the set a destination for query results already in the console Query Settings, that's when I get this error. Open a fresh tab and try again.

Answer (score 4):

already it can be done like
`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project.dataset.table AS SELECT x,y,z FROM 'project.dataset.mnp'`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE [GCP_Folder].abc AS SELECT x,y,z FROM mnp
```

This wont get the error **Cannot set write disposition in jobs with DDL statements**. no source to refer, its trial and error from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table using another table as the starting point.
This method basically allows you to duplicate another table (or a part
of it, if you add a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement).

```
CREATE TABLE project_name.dataset_name.table (your destination) AS SELECT column_a,column_b,... FROM (UNION/JOIN for example)
```